# golang vnc connetion error - out of memory

Tags: go, vnc

I have vnc application wited in go, the problem is after same time execution crash, with the message out of memory.

The complete log is here: https://ghostbin.com/paste/3wpcm

the complete code of client.go where exist this error is this: https://ghostbin.com/paste/bgn7s

does anyone know why this application is out of memory? my Linux machine has 16gb ram memory.

Comment: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error **and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself**.*

Answer (score 0):

[Profile memory usage](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Performance#memory-profiler) of your program:

> Memory profiler shows what functions allocate heap memory. You can collect it in similar ways as CPU profile: with `go test --memprofile` (http://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Description_of_testing_flags), with `net/http/pprof` via http://myserver:6060:/debug/pprof/heap or by calling `runtime/pprof.WriteHeapProfile`.
>
> <…>